# How to prevent loading a mozilla addon?

Tags: firefox, javascript

There is a firefox addon that I have installed. It executes after the current page is completely loaded. I want to prevent this addon to be able to run on my website. How can I prevent the content-script.js file in addon from loading (I want to change my website so the extension cant work there.)?

Comment: Uninstall the expansion and/or check whenever it allows for exceptions.

Comment: Your goal isn’t clear to me. Do you want to _change your website_ to not make the extension work there? Or do you want to _change your browser setup_ (in whatever way) to not make the extension run on specific websites?

Comment: change my website so the extension  cant work there. If I can override the variables in content-script.js from my website I can also achieve this.

Comment: You should [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1515328/edit) with this clarification. This unfortunately makes the question off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content scripts run in a different context as opposed to regular scripts on your website. That means scripts on your page cannot interfere with them. (Only indirectly via DOM and messages.) It also means that content scripts cannot directly access scripting objects on your page. (Only indirectly by injecting JS code, which is observable.)

As a website developer, you cannot block them. This is by design.